# Please add a @NgModule annotation. Angular 4/Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I got an error listing when I tried to build project:

```
ERROR in Error: Unexpected value 'MdButtonModule in /tmp/app/node_modules/@angular/material/material.d.ts' imported by the module 'CoreModule in /tmp/app/src/app/core/core.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

This is my `core.module`:

```
import {
  MdCardModule,
  MdGridListModule,
  MdSelectModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MdButtonModule,
} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TabsModule.forRoot(), AccordionModule.forRoot(), BsDropdownModule.forRoot(), BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpModule,
    TranslateModule,
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ToasterModule,
    MdButtonModule
  ]...
```

As you can notice I imported module `MdButtonModule` and added that to `@NgModule`.

Comment: which version of material ?

Comment: `"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8"`

Comment: It tries to find button in path: `app/node_modules/@angular/material/material.d.ts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See beta.11 release notes
https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.11

In section **Breaking changes - Deprecation of "md" prefix**

(Using @angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.8" installs latest version on beta channel)

Answer (score 0):

reread this https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

it say that you have to implement other things

Comment: I did the same things.

Comment: @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";.....
import 'hammerjs';....